# Why using static variables inside a function makes it runs slower?

Tags: c++

I made a function with static initiation at the beginning in order to calculate values only the first time the function is called, but then the function runs slower.

It is used VS2017 on windows10 (I5 processor 3.5Ghz)

Here is the result:

[image]

```
const static double: 20ms
static double: 16ms
double only: 5.1ms
sum only: 5ms
```

Here is the code. `function1` is the slowest one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

//=============== TIMER PART =================
#ifdef __linux__ 
#include <unistd.h>    //usleep()
typedef std::chrono::system_clock t_clock;    //try to use high_resolution_clock on  new linux x64 computer!
#else
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock t_clock;
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#endif
std::chrono::time_point<t_clock> start_time, stop_time = start_time; char null_char = '\0';
void timer(const char *title = 0, int data_size = 1) { stop_time = t_clock::now(); double us = (double)chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(stop_time - start_time).count(); if (title) printf("%s time = %7lgms = %7lg MOPs\n", title, (double)us*1e-3, (double)data_size / us); start_time = t_clock::now(); }
//=============== TIMER PART =================

double f1(double x)
{
    const static double a=100.1,b=3+sqrt(a),c=10+sin(b/45)+cos(b/45+a),d=c+tan(b/105.3);
    return x+d;
}

double f2(double x)
{
    static double a=100.1,b=3+sqrt(a),c=10+sin(b/45)+cos(b/45+a),d=c+tan(b/105.3);
    return x+d;
}

double f3(double x)
{
    double a=100.1,b=3+sqrt(a),c=10+sin(b/45)+cos(b/45+a),d=c+tan(b/105.3);
    return x+d;
}

double f4(double x)
{
    return x+17.33;
}

int main()
{
    int i,top=500000;
    double sum=0.0;
    timer();
    for (i=0;i<top;i++)
    {
        sum+=f1(i*10.0);sum+=f1(i*10.0);sum+=f1(i*10.0);sum+=f1(i*10.0);sum+=f1(i*10.0);
        sum+=f1(i*10.0);sum+=f1(i*10.0);sum+=f1(i*10.0);sum+=f1(i*10.0);sum+=f1(i*10.0);
    }
    timer("const static double",top*10);
    for (i=0;i<top;i++)
    {
        sum+=f2(i*10.0);sum+=f2(i*10.0);sum+=f2(i*10.0);sum+=f2(i*10.0);sum+=f2(i*10.0);
        sum+=f2(i*10.0);sum+=f2(i*10.0);sum+=f2(i*10.0);sum+=f2(i*10.0);sum+=f2(i*10.0);
    }
    timer("static double",top*10);
    for (i=0;i<top;i++)
    {
        sum+=f3(i*10.0);sum+=f3(i*10.0);sum+=f3(i*10.0);sum+=f3(i*10.0);sum+=f3(i*10.0);
        sum+=f3(i*10.0);sum+=f3(i*10.0);sum+=f3(i*10.0);sum+=f3(i*10.0);sum+=f3(i*10.0);
    }
    timer("double",top*10);
    for (i=0;i<top;i++)
    {
        sum+=f4(i*10.0);sum+=f4(i*10.0);sum+=f4(i*10.0);sum+=f4(i*10.0);sum+=f4(i*10.0);
        sum+=f4(i*10.0);sum+=f4(i*10.0);sum+=f4(i*10.0);sum+=f4(i*10.0);sum+=f4(i*10.0);
    }
    timer("sum only",top*10);
    cout<<sum<<endl;

    cout<<"\n=== FIN ==="<<endl;
    getchar();return 1;
}
```

Comment: Try running the functions f{1..4} in a different order, e.g., f4, f3, f2, f1.  What happens?  You may be experiencing an effect which is related more to machine-level optimizations than C++-level differences.

Comment: Accessing static variables takes work. https://godbolt.org/z/n259T- No repro for the `const static` case btw.

Comment: I'm wondering why are you using static variables inside those functions.

Comment: >>Try running the functions f{1..4} in a different order, e.g., f4, f3, f2, f1:  similar results

Answer (score 8):

Because the compiler must ensure that static local variable initialization is performed only once even in a multi-threaded environment.

So local static variable initialization is surrounded by a thread safe guard which is expensive. That is the reason why the use of static local variable is discouraged.

Comment: Thank you, I will remove const static from my code. Can anybody run the code on linux to see also the performance?